# What is this error with not being able to find a file?

Tags: npm, webstorm

I am trying to make a react app in WebStorm, but I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Pravi\WebstormProjects\newstore/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Pravi\WebstormProjects\newstore\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pravi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-25T01_31_51_956Z-debug.log
```

How do I fix this or what should I take a look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't have a `package.json` file. To fix that run

```
npm init
```